# what does $\frac{\text{d}x}{x}$ mean?

Tags: calculus, integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I saw in a lecture recently the Gamma-function written like $$\Gamma (k) = \int_0^\infty e^{-x} x^k \frac{\text{d}x}{x}$$
and the professor said, that the integral was with respect to the measure $\frac{\text{d}x}{x}$. How is this meant? If I am given a set $A$ in $\mathbf{R}$, how could I for instance calculate $\frac{\text{d}x}{x}(A)$?

Thanks!

Comment: If $A=[a,b]$, I guess $\mathrm{d}x/x(A)=\mathrm{d}\log x (A)=\log(b)-\log(a)$ (but I am not sure).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The measure $\frac{dx}{x}$ assigns the measure $\int_A \frac{1}{x} dx$ to a set $A$ (implicitly considered to be a subset of $[0,\infty)$ so that you guarantee positivity). Note that in this notation Lebesgue measure is sometimes denoted by just $dx$.

Comment: what would then be the advantage of writing the Gamma-function like above?

Comment: I'm not sure, maybe because $\frac{dx}{x}$ is also $d \log(x)$, so that one can substitute $u=\log(x)$ to modify the problem?

Comment: @Steven $\dfrac{dx}{x}$ is multiplication-invariant, for all (Lebesgue) measurable $A \subset (0,+\infty)$ and $k\in (0,+\infty)$ we have $$\int_A \frac{dx}{x} = \int_{k\cdot A} \frac{dx}{x}.$$ $\dfrac{dx}{x}$ is the (well, a, Haar measures are only unique up to multiplication with constants) [Haar measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haar_measure) on the topological group $(0,+\infty)$. That's why, when working on $(0,+\infty)$, the measure $\dfrac{dx}{x}$ is often more natural/convenient/useful than $dx$.